# How to remove MySQL from Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: mysql

I tried to move my datadir on a working MySql install, which apparently I messed up.

I have tried to uninstall / reinstall numerous times, only to get the same errors on reinstall.

The mysql/error.log is giving me this:

```
150118 11:54:44 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150118 11:54:44 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150118 11:54:44 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150118 11:54:44 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
150118 11:54:44 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150118 11:54:44 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
150118 11:54:44 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150118 11:54:44  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'create'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

I have chowned and chmodded until I am blue in the face, I get the same errors regardless. I have also followed many threads on how to uninstall MySQL, only to have the same result on reinstall.

After an install attempt I get this error:

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
150118 11:58:01 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/yosemite.lower-test
150118 11:58:01 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/yosemite.lower-test
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

MySQL is the owner of /var/lib/mysql/, and the file permissions should allow writing.

I don't need to preserve any databases, I just need to kill this thing and get it reinstalled and working!

Any help will be most appreciated, thanks in advance!

rw

Answer (score 1):

I have gotten MySQL uninstalled, and reinstalled, which I am still pinching myself about.

The solution was simple enough. I am sure I performed these actions somewhere in the blur of trying to figure this out, but for anyone looking for a solution, this is what I did:

Purge mysql-server-5.1 and mysql-common.
Afterwards, delete /var/lib/mysql /etc/mysql and /var/log/mysql.
Then I restarted the machine.

src: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1407998&p=9332936#post9332936

Again, not sure why this worked now, when I have done all of the various steps in other tries, but I am not going to look a gift horse in the mouth. Hopefully someone else finds this useful.